# Equivalent of Marshal.PtrToStructure in Unsafe class?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

None of the methods in `Unsafe` class do work when trying to read a structure from a pointer.

They all display *Unable to read memory* in the debugger:

```
var info1 = Marshal.PtrToStructure<DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO_V>(pSymInfo); // works
var info2 = Unsafe.AsRef<DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO_V>((void*)pSymInfo); // unable to read memory
var info3 = Unsafe.Read<DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO_V>((void*)pSymInfo); // unable to read memory
var info4 = Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO_V>((void*)pSymInfo); // unable to read memory
```

Is it possible to read a structure with `Unsafe` class just as `Marshal.PtrToStructure` does?

About:

`pSymInfo` is an `IntPtr`.

[SYMBOL_INFO_V](https://github.com/dahall/Vanara/blob/e5bca53d630aa481bb4426b1d81e660a56e20717/PInvoke/DbgHelp/DbgHelp.Structs.cs#L2358):

```
public struct SYMBOL_INFO_V
{
    public uint SizeOfStruct;
    public uint TypeIndex;
    public ulong Reserved0;
    private ulong Reserved1;
    public uint Index;
    public uint Size;
    public ulong ModBase;
    public SYMFLAG Flags; // enum, uint
    public ulong Value;
    public ulong Address;
    public uint Register;
    public uint Scope;
    public uint Tag;
    public uint NameLen;
    public uint MaxNameLen;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1)]
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Can we see what pSymInfo is here, and where it came from? And can we see SYMBOL_INFO_V ? Without more context, it is hard to know whether "punning" will work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question with requested details.

Comment: The Name field prevents using Unsafe, it requires a conversion.  Not the only problem, this struct is tricky because its size is variable.  In other words, SizeConst = 1 is not correct.  It is just long enough to store the string.  You could hack it by leaving the Name field out of the structure declaration, then marshal the string manually (if MaxNameLen isn't 0) with Marshal.PtrToStringUni().

Comment: Got it, I'll let good old Marshal class do its magic with this non-conventional struct.

Comment: This is because Unsafe understands managed objects, not native blitted "as is" projections. For example look at Unsafe.SizeOf remarks "This API returns the size of the managed view of the type. For the size of the unmanaged view of the type, such as needed for interop purposes, use Marshal.SizeOf". To prove this, just use Unsafe.Write of a SYMBOL_INFO_V in memory and have a look at it, it's not what you'd expect (it's not equivalent to Marshal.StructureToPtr), and the Name characters are not there (since in .NET world, they are stored in another piece of memory)

Comment: Put it another way: Unsafe knows nothing about .NET p/invoke feature, only Marshal does.

Comment: Indeed, that's the simplest and best explanation one could give about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Unsafe class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe) has no knowledge of P/Invoke rules, only the [Marshal class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal) does.

For example, if you take this little program:

```
unsafe internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var info = new MyStruct();
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf<MyStruct>()); // 8
        Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.SizeOf<MyStruct>()); // 16
        info.SomeValue = 0x12345678;
        info.Name = "Test";
        var p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(100);
        var ptr = p.ToPointer();
        Unsafe.Write(ptr, info);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public uint SomeValue;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)] // includes terminating zero
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

And debug it with a breakpoint after the `Unsafe.Write` method, open a memory window and use ptr as the start address, and you'll see this:

[image]

The `SomeValue` member is visible, but the `Name` is not, because `ptr` points to the managed object (with a probable leading pointer to something internal), not to it's P/invoke "projection".

Also, note in this case `Marshal.SizeOf` (P/Invoke size = 8) and `Unsafe.SizeOf` (Managed size = 16) results are different.

Answer (score 0):

What type of string you're trying to read?

You can use the [`fixed` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#fixed-size-buffers) to read raw byte/char array in a struct:

```
public fixed byte Name[5];
```

Note that in .NET, all char/string is in Unicode, with each character taking 2 bytes. If you're trying to read an ascii/ansi string you should read them as bytes then use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` to convert it to managed string. You should read them as char array if you're using wchar_t in unmanged code.

If the struct does not contain the actual string, but a pointer(char*/wchar_t*). You can read it as `IntPtr` then convert it with `Marshal.PtrToString*`

P.S.

Instead of using `Unsafe`, you can just read the struct with pointers:

```
var myStruct = *(SYMBOL_INFO_V*)pSymInfo;
```

Comment: I don't really have a problem reading that actual string, just trying to understand why Marshal class is required, turns out that a string in a struct is by definition incorrect as pointed out above, but the Marshal class knows how to deal with that with these attributes, hence why it'd never work with Unsafe class.